# VS Crashes with RAZOR VBHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

For some reason, with the Razor view engine, VS is crashing on me.  I copied the CSHTML content over to a VBHTML file and begin reformatting it, and VS has crashed on me twice now as I change a helper or function method syntax from:

```
@helper SomeHelper(string text)
```

to

```
@Helper SomeHelper(text As String)
```

Is anyone else getting this?  The whole machine must be rebooted to get intellisense/markup highlighing to work.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  Email ScottGu@Microsoft.com.

Comment: I *suspect* this is one of the glitches that is fixed in VS SP1; I distinctly remember intellisense being mentioned...

Comment: OK, so wait for the final SP release, which I assume SP1 hasn't been released yet...

Comment: When in doubt, you can alwasy file bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/ and let the product team tell you if they've fixed it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, I suggest that you install SP1. Support for Razor views is improved.

[Link to Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en)

[Link to Change list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509)